# C# WCF Dynamically

Tags: c#, wcf

My Req. is I want to call WCF Service Dynamically, just WSDL and interface name and method name will be provided, arguments given in dictionary/any collection. I want to call an operation contract dynamically which has parametrs as simple type and complex types.

My Service:-

```
public class CalculatorService : ICalculator
{
    public double Add(double n1, double n2)
    {
        return n1 + n2;
    }
    public EmployeeOutput ProcessEmployee(EmployeeInput obj,string str, int i)
    {
        EmployeeOutput objOut = new EmployeeOutput();
        objOut.EmpNo = obj.EmpNo;
        objOut.EmpName = obj.EmpName;
        return objOut;
    }
[DataContract]
    public class EmployeeInput
    {
    [DataMember]
    public string EmpNo { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string EmpName { get; set; }
}
```

From client, I am trying to do this, since I had complex Type(EmployeeInput and primitive type string, int) and in complex type I had properties and fields, issue I am facing is mapping the inputs to service parameters for complex types as well as primitive types.  My Code at client:

```
    static class ObjectExtensions
    {
        public static void SetPropertyValue<T>(this object obj, string propertyName, T propertyValue)
        where T : IConvertible
    {
        PropertyInfo pi = obj.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName);

        if (pi != null && pi.CanWrite)
        {
            pi.SetValue
            (
                obj,
                Convert.ChangeType(propertyValue, pi.PropertyType),
                null
            );
        }
    }
}
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CompilerResults compilerResults = null;

        object proxyInstance = GetProxyInstance(ref compilerResults);
        string operationName = "ProcessEmployee";
        MethodInfo methodInfo = proxyInstance.GetType().GetMethod(operationName);
        ParameterInfo[] paramInfos = methodInfo.GetParameters();
        OrderedDictionary valueList = new OrderedDictionary();
        IList<Object> parameter = new List<Object>();
              //Object[] parameter = new Object[10];
        for (int paramIndex = 0; paramIndex < paramInfos.Length; paramIndex++)
        {
            int i = 1;
            var parameterType = paramInfos[paramIndex].ParameterType;
            bool IsPrimitive = parameterType.GetType().IsPrimitive;
            Object parameter2 = new Object();
            if (parameterType.Namespace.StartsWith("System"))
            {
                parameter2.SetPropertyValue("str", "Test");
                //parameterType.GetProperties()[i].SetValue(parameter2, "Test", null);
            }
            else
            {
                parameter2 = compilerResults.CompiledAssembly.CreateInstance(parameterType.FullName, false, BindingFlags.CreateInstance, null, null, null, null);
                EmployeeInput obj = new EmployeeInput();
                obj.EmpNo = "123";
                obj.EmpName = "Test";
                Console.WriteLine(parameter2.GetType());
                Console.WriteLine(obj.GetType());
                parameter2.SetPropertyValue("EmpNo", 123);
                parameter2.SetPropertyValue("EmpName", "Test");
                //parameterType.GetProperties()[i].SetValue(parameter2, Convert.ChangeType(obj, parameter2.GetType()), null);
                //parameterType.GetProperties()[i].SetValue(parameter2, obj, null);
            }
            parameter.Add(parameter2);
            //parameter[paramIndex] = parameter2;
            i++;
        }
 object[] operationParameters = new object[] { parameter };
 var result = methodInfo.Invoke(proxyInstance, BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, operationParameters, null);
```

The above code is failing when mapping complex fields. I mean from client, client send a collection, ex:- Dictionary collection with complex types, primitive types, I should be able to invoke my operationContract at service Side, this is my requirement.

WSDL Code Generation I'm already doing in CreateInstance,

```
        public static object GetProxyInstance(ref CompilerResults compilerResults)
    {
        object proxyInstance = null;
        // Define the WSDL Get address, contract name and parameters, with this we can extract WSDL details any time
        //Uri address = new Uri("http://localhost:8732/CalculatorService/?wsdl");
        //Uri address = new Uri("http://localhost/APG.WCFService/APGService.svc?wsdl");
        Uri address = new Uri("http://localhost:8732/CalculatorService/?wsdl");
        // For HttpGet endpoints use a Service WSDL address a mexMode of .HttpGet and for MEX endpoints use a MEX address and a mexMode of .MetadataExchange
        MetadataExchangeClientMode mexMode = MetadataExchangeClientMode.HttpGet;
        string contractName = "ICalculator";
        //string contractName = "IAPGService";
        // Get the metadata file from the service.
        MetadataExchangeClient metadataExchangeClient = new MetadataExchangeClient(address, mexMode);
        metadataExchangeClient.ResolveMetadataReferences = true;
        //One can also provide credentials if service needs that by the help following two lines.
        //ICredentials networkCredential = new NetworkCredential("", "", "");
        //metadataExchangeClient.HttpCredentials = networkCredential;
        //Gets the meta data information of the service.
        MetadataSet metadataSet = metadataExchangeClient.GetMetadata();
        // Import all contracts and endpoints.
        WsdlImporter wsdlImporter = new WsdlImporter(metadataSet);
        //Import all contracts.
        Collection<ContractDescription> contracts = wsdlImporter.ImportAllContracts();
        //Import all end points.
        ServiceEndpointCollection allEndpoints = wsdlImporter.ImportAllEndpoints();
        // Generate type information for each contract.
        ServiceContractGenerator serviceContractGenerator = new ServiceContractGenerator();
        //Dictinary has been defined to keep all the contract endpoints present, contract name is key of the dictionary item.
        var endpointsForContracts = new Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<ServiceEndpoint>>();
        foreach (ContractDescription contract in contracts)
        {
            serviceContractGenerator.GenerateServiceContractType(contract);
            // Keep a list of each contract's endpoints.
            endpointsForContracts[contract.Name] = allEndpoints.Where(ep => ep.Contract.Name == contract.Name).ToList();
        }
        // Generate a code file for the contracts.
        CodeGeneratorOptions codeGeneratorOptions = new CodeGeneratorOptions();
        codeGeneratorOptions.BracingStyle = "C";
        // Create Compiler instance of a specified language.
        CodeDomProvider codeDomProvider = CodeDomProvider.CreateProvider("C#");
        // Adding WCF-related assemblies references as copiler parameters, so as to do the compilation of particular service contract.
        CompilerParameters compilerParameters = new CompilerParameters(new string[] { "System.dll", "System.ServiceModel.dll", "System.Runtime.Serialization.dll" });
        compilerParameters.GenerateInMemory = true;
        //Gets the compiled assembly.
        compilerResults = codeDomProvider.CompileAssemblyFromDom(compilerParameters, serviceContractGenerator.TargetCompileUnit);
        if (compilerResults.Errors.Count <= 0)
        {
            // Find the proxy type that was generated for the specified contract (identified by a class that implements the contract and ICommunicationbject - this is contract 
            //implemented by all the communication oriented objects).
            Type proxyType = compilerResults.CompiledAssembly.GetTypes().First(t => t.IsClass && t.GetInterface(contractName) != null &&
                t.GetInterface(typeof(ICommunicationObject).Name) != null);
            // Now we get the first service endpoint for the particular contract.
            ServiceEndpoint serviceEndpoint = endpointsForContracts[contractName].First();
            // Create an instance of the proxy by passing the endpoint binding and address as parameters.
            proxyInstance = compilerResults.CompiledAssembly.CreateInstance(proxyType.Name, false, System.Reflection.BindingFlags.CreateInstance, null,
                new object[] { serviceEndpoint.Binding, serviceEndpoint.Address }, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, null);
        }
        return proxyInstance;


    }
```

Thanks In Advance,

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you make use of the [Wsdl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7h3ystb6%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) utility tool to generate the web service proxy dynamically. Then using the CodeDom to compile the code to a runtime assembly and call it dynamically from your code.

Comment: Hi Neil, I'm already using WSDL to generate the proxy. But my question is how to invoke method in WCF Service with simple & complex types.

Comment: Well I do not see the reason why you want to map the parameters be it simple or complex type like that using reflection. For you still going to end up hard coding the mapping between values and the parameter types. You surely just need to pass the correct instance types to the method.Invoke member:

    var parameter = new EmployeeInput {EmpNo = 123};